# Inserting a new record into mysql tables and adding new records with same id for multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am designing a Diabetes management system and my question is about inserting a new record in two of the tables. I have a user table with the fields: 
user_ID (PK), Username, password, etc
I also have the profile table, which stores personal information about a user. Profile:
User_ID (FK from user table), Firstname, LastName, Address, etc.

I have stored the user_id in the profile table as a foreign key because i want to have a user associated with their own profile. E.G. a person with username grover with User_Id '3' will have a profile with personal info and the user_ID in the profile table will also be '3'. I hope the above makes sense. My question is, when i have stored the data from the form into variables, how would i write the query so that the new record will be created and the right fields will be stored in the correct table with the new record having the same user_ID in both the user and profile table.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at [LAST_INSERT_ID](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) function. This will give you the PK of the record you just entered, ie your user_id which you can use in the corresponding join tables

```
    insert into Users values (null,'asdf','asdf',3,1);
    Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

    mysql> select last_insert_id();
    +------------------+
    | last_insert_id() |
    +------------------+
    |                1 |
    +------------------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There you go

Comment: So would it be right to do the following? insert into user
(User_id, Username, Password)
values('', '$Username', '$Password');

and then insert the other parts of the form into the other tables as follows:
insert into profile
(User_ID, FirstName, LastName)
Values('LAST_INSERT_ID()', '$FirstName', '$LastName');

Comment: As long as you're sure no one else (including you) is inserting rows into your database between these two calls

Comment: Is there an alternative, as it may be a that another record is created? I don't think it will happen as there will be 2 concecutive queries after the data gathering from the registration form. I shall try it.

Comment: I dont think there's an alternative. You just have to use last insert id function.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the below queries, but the profile tables is given the id 0 and not the last incremental id. insert into user (User_id, Username, Password)
values(null, 'John', 'John')

insert into profile (User_id, FirstName, LastName)
values(LAST_INSERT_ID(),'Sundeep','Singh')

Comment: Does your table have auto increment set on it's primary key ?

Comment: Yes the user table has that setup. It get the next id when i ran this query.

Comment: The LAST_INSERT_ID is returning 0 and not the last ID. I am testing this in phpmyadmin in the same window that is opened. So assuming this doesn't close and reopen the connection for the second query?

Comment: Ah here we are. CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `User_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `User_level` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `SuperUser` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`User_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1